# Crock pot on power inverter

Tags: inverter, wiring, battery-operated, electrical, electricity

I have a slow cooker crock pot thats uses 120 volts AC which range from 0.6 amps to 2 amps and consume electricity that ranges from 70 watts (low temperature) to 250 watts (high temperature). When I look at the label on the bottom of the slow cooker, it says AC current only.

I have a 105 amp 12 volt marine deep cycle battery and an 1100 watt power inverter and a 6 gauge wire that connects the two.

I have a very limited knowledge with electrical appliances and I was wondering does the label mean I can only use AC power and I cannot use a battery powered inverter? Or does it mean it uses that many amps if it is using 120 volt AC power.

Picture of label
https://photos.app.goo.gl/jKnHZmaqxXZ56UDx8

Comment: The heating element wouldn't care if it was AC or DC, but any electronics might care. Certainly if a transformer was used to create a low voltage, it would require AC. Even a "dumb" crock-pot with a bi-metallic strip could be stressed with DC. Switches have a lower voltage and/or current rating when used with DC.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the inverter is to make "home-made" AC power from your battery's DC power, so you can power normal home appliances.

So, yes, you can use that slow cooker using the output of the inverter.  However, on high power, the cooker will draw about 2 Amp at 120 V, and the inverter will draw about 20 Amp from your 12 V battery to produce that.  Your 105 Ah battery would be very dead in 4 hours or so.

Comment: The average current draw will be less once it reaches operating temperature and the thermostatic control begins to switch it on and off.